# If i backspace textfieldwidget or textaheadfield till nothing was left, it gets an error flutter

Tags: flutter

[image: Error preview]

just simple question, its the error like that is normal? or not?
that error is given when i backspace till the textfield have nothing left. i don't know what the cause of it

```
Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Email', border: InputBorder.none),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 2),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: passwordController,
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password', border: InputBorder.none),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100),
          child: ElevatedButton.icon(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
            ),
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.lock_open,
              size: 20,
            ),
            label: const Text(
              'Sign in',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: signIn,
          ),
        ),
```

truthfully all my textfield is acting like that, i don't know how to fix it. it should be looks like any normal textfield.

Comment: I dont think its normal. Can you share your textfield

Comment: @EmreFarukKOLAÇ Thankyou for replying, i shared it in the question

Comment: Do you use your textfield in a stateful or stateless widget?

Comment: i use statefullwidget

Comment: Sorry dude, I could not reproduce the problem. I saw some solutions containing reloading the app but I dont think it will also helpful. Hopefully ignoring the warning would not result in any mistakes

Comment: @EmreFarukKOLAÇ its ok sir thankyou for replying this problem